# Discord.js Missing Property 'name'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make an embed, but it throws an error that it is missing the `name` property. The embed is meant to show the content and author of a message as well as the score that it has received.

Here's the code for the embed:

```js
const suggestionEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('Suggestion')
  .setDescription(`A suggestion from ${message.author}`)
  .setAuthor(message.author)
  .setThumbnail(suggestionSender.displayAvatarURL())
  .addFields(
    { name: 'Suggestion', value: `${message.content}` },
    { name: 'Score', value: `${score}` },
  )
  .setColor(0xffcc00);
```

I can't tell what the difference is between it and the other embeds I made that is causing this issue. The code is throwing this error:

```
errors: [
    [
      'name',
      MissingPropertyError: A required property is missing
          at ObjectValidator.handleIgnoreStrategy (/home/container/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1243:27)
          at ObjectValidator.handleStrategy (/home/container/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1121:47)
          at ObjectValidator.handle (/home/container/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1221:17)
          at ObjectValidator.parse (/home/container/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:212:88)
          at EmbedBuilder.setAuthor (/home/container/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:291:26)
          at Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/functions.js:64:127)
          at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
          at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:28:14)
          at module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
          at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:354:31) {
        property: 'name'
      }
    ]
  ]
```

I tried changing the values of the fields to see what the problem was but could not find a way that fixed the error and still made the embed the way I wanted.

Comment: @Zsolt Meszaros Sorry, thank you for telling me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `setAuthor` accepts an object with the key, `name`:

```js
const suggestionEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('Suggestion')
  .setDescription(`A suggestion from ${message.author}`)
  .setAuthor({name: message.author.displayName})
  .setThumbnail(suggestionSender.displayAvatarURL())
  .addFields(
    { name: 'Suggestion', value: `${message.content}` },
    { name: 'Score', value: `${score}` },
  )
  .setColor(0xffcc00);
```

If you also want to include an icon, you can add an `iconURL` too with the icon's URL.